# Cannot figure out how to free my structure

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, free

I need to free() all the memory allocated for my structure config.

```
struct keysnvalues {
char* key;
char* value;
};

struct section {
char *name;
struct keysnvalues *keysnvalues;
int keysnvalues_ammount;
};

struct config {
struct section *sections;
int section_ammount;
};
```

In the beggining of the code I do this

```
struct section * sect = malloc(sizeof(struct section) * 255);
struct keysnvalues * keysnvalue = malloc(sizeof(struct keysnvalues) * 255);
```

If I want to add section I do this for the first one

```
sect[++num_section].name = buffer; // buffer is the name
```

And for the next sections

```
sect[num_section].keysnvalues = keysnvalue;
sect[num_section].keysnvalues_ammount = num_keysnvalues;
cfg -> section_ammount++;

            //start with new keysnvalue
num_keysnvalues = 0;
keysnvalue = malloc(sizeof(struct keysnvalues) * 255);
sect[++num_section].name = buffer;
sect[num_section].keysnvalues = 0;
```

If I want to add a key and a value to section I am working with I do this

```
keysnvalue[num_keysnvalues].key = key;
keysnvalue[num_keysnvalues++].value = value;
```

The whole code is here: https://pastebin.com/pGztJ9k4

I am aware of the fact that this is probably a stupid question, but I could not figure out how to free the whole structure config for hours now.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `free(keysnvalue);`?

Comment: I suspect there is a *lot* more going on than just this code. Something tells me `key`. `value`, and `name` are also dynamic, and the management of *all* of this is significantly more involved than the trivialization portrayed here. Regardless, the [documentation for `free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) gives good insights as to how /when to use it.

Comment: @WhozCraig But if I don't call malloc on section[i].name, doing just free(section[i]) should be okay, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should `free()` a pointer if and only if it has been allocated through `malloc()`. To achieve this, you have to make sure not to "loose" any pointer to a `malloc`ed memory address, e.g. by assigning `malloc` several times to the same variable without having copied it's previous value or without having freed the previously assigned memory.

I did not analyse the complete code you referred to.
But it seems as if you copy the value of `keysnvalue` to the current section before `malloc`ing a new value for `sect[i].keysnvalues`.
Hence, it seems that each section get's its own `keysnvalue`, and you can loop it through:

```
for (int i=0;i< num_section;i++) {
   if (sect[i].keysnvalues != NULL) {
      free(sect[i].keysnvalues);
      // free(sect[i].name);  // if buffer has also been malloced
   }
}
free (keysnvalue);
free (sect);
```

It may be that you also have to loop trough each `sect[i].keysnvalue` in order to eventually free `key/value`.

Make sure that section members that you are going to `free` at the end of the program are always initialised either with `NULL` or a `malloc`ed value in order to prevent your code from "freeing" a garbage pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

When you reset 'keysnvalue' with the next 'malloc()', you are *overwriting* the pointer to the previous value of 'keysnvalue'.  That leaves the associated storage unreachable, i.e a 'memory leak' [unless you maintain a copy of the previous value of 'keysnvalue' in another location].  If you are really replacing the structure with a fresh one, you must 'free()' the old one first, AND THEN 'malloc()' the next one - you cannot wait until the end to clean up everything.

Personally I wouldn't do it that way - for a fresh structure, I would call 'memset()' to zero out the existing structure.

Comment: So basically by calling "keysnvalue = malloc(sizeof(struct keysnvalues) * 255);" everytime I want to add another keysnvalue into a section I make it impossible to free() it?